# How to print instance name based on instance id using boto 3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

How can I retrieve an instance name based on InstanceId using boto3?

```
connection = boto3.resource('ec2')
instances = connection.instances.filter(InstanceIds=[instanceid])
        for instance in instances:
            instance_name=???
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to get the `Name` tag:

```
def get_name(instance):
    for tag in instance.tags:
        if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
            return tag['Value']
```